# Run method in new process

Tags: c#, .net, process

is it possible to run method in new child process? In my example I can execute method Run, which will execute private method doAction in new process (not thread!)

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void Run()
    {
        //what should I do there to run 'doAction' in new process?
        doAction();

    }

    private void doAction()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would Thread not be sufficient? Why would you ever need 2 `myprogram.exe`'s running at once, just to run a method? (if that's even possible.)

Comment: My question is rather curiosity than real problem. I want to know is it possible

Comment: To better understand this problem I think we need to better understand your overall way of thinking -tell us what you're trying to achieve (not technically but from a function perspective) so we can better understand.

Comment: A reason to do this would be to execute a long running method not capable of cooperative termination.

Comment: @sircapsalot Another reason to use a second `myprogram.exe` is if `doAction` needs to be executed in a process started with "Run as administrator."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processes do not share memory and require a mechanism between them to communicate. You can use one of a variety mechanisms for this:

1. File or data - one process writes to a file or DB, the other reads
   from and executes some method based on the data or file content
2. Service host/client - use WCF, .NET Remoting, Named Pipes or direct
   TCP/IP communication mechanism where one process hosts a service
   interface implementation and the calling process (the client) uses a
   proxy of the service interface to serialize and communicate the call
   to the host process - this is the best approach if you want a
   stateful request/response interaction
3. Message queue - use a message
   queue like MSMQ where one process sends a message to the queue and
   the other picks it up and executes the method

I'm sure there are others but these are the three most common methods.

My favorite is a light weight service host/client scenario. There are several lightweight utilities to make this easy for you. You can use [RemotingLite](http://remotinglite.codeplex.com/) or my own extension of RemotingLite which supports Named Pipes called [DuoVia.Net](https://nuget.org/packages/DuoVia.Net/).